# mercurial on macos doesn't read ~/.config/hg/hgrc

Tags: macos, mercurial, config, hgrc

I installed mercurial on my Mabook-Air (M1) using:

```
brew install mercurial
```

Mercurial (6.1.2) is working fine, but the configurations files that I copied over from my Linux setup (everything under `~/.config/hg/` including `hgrc` and a global `hgignore`) cannot be found.

`man hgrc` indicates that `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/hg/hgrc` is consulted under Unix. Is macOS not considered Unix?

Answer (score 4):

Running `hg config --debug | fgrep 'read config'` on (Arch) Linux gives:

```
read config from: resource:mercurial.defaultrc.mergetools.rc
read config from: /usr/local/etc/mercurial/hgrc
read config from: /etc/mercurial/hgrc
read config from: /home/anthon/.hgrc
read config from: /home/anthon/.config/hg/hgrc
```

whereas on macOS it gives:

```
read config from: resource:mercurial.defaultrc.mergetools.rc
read config from: /opt/homebrew/etc/mercurial/hgrc
read config from: /etc/mercurial/hgrc
read config from: /Users/anthon/.hgrc
```

If you don't want to clobber your home directory with another hidden file `~/.hgrc`, you can do:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/mercurial   # wasn't there on my system
echo '%include ~/.config/hg/hgrc' | sudo tee -a /etc/mercurial/hgrc
```

After which your `~/.config/hg/hgrc` should be read on mercurial startup.

Unfortunately using `hg config --edit` not only tries to edit `~/.hgrc`, but it also creates it even if you quit your editor without making changes. After that your username will be unset (as `~/.hgrc` is read after `/etc/mercurial/hgrc`